# How to add a custom validator to an ion-input in Ionic 2? ex. Check for min/max

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am creating an Angular2-Ionic2 TypeScript based app, and have a problem with ion-inputs which don't seem to recognize min, max validator attributes as regular input would.
Other validators I might need to create is going to be a duplicate validator and a whole number validator.
In a nutshell, I need an idea of creating a robust set of validators.

Answer (score 2):

FIRST WAY is pretty nice, that I think is best for me, as I have 4 validators and can refer to them by wrapping all in a class that i named CustomValidators

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { FormControl, Validator, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class CustomValidators {
    static duplicates(existing: string[]) {
        return (control: FormControl) => {

           let valid = existing.map(s => s.toLowerCase().trim())
              .indexOf(control.value.toLowerCase().trim()) === -1

           return valid ? null : {
               duplicates: {
                   valid: false
             }
         }
     }
 }
  static min(min: number) {
    return (control: FormControl) => {
        console.log('min' + (parseInt(control.value) >= min));
        let valid =  parseInt(control.value) >= min;

        return valid ? null : {
            min: {
                valid: false
            }
        }
    }
}
  static max(max: number) {
    return (control: FormControl) => {
        console.log('max' + (parseInt(control.value) <= max));

        let valid = parseInt(control.value) <= max;

        return valid ? null : {
            max: {
                valid: false
            }
        }
    }
}
  static wholeNumber(control: FormControl) {
    console.log('wholeNumber' + (parseFloat(control.value) % 1 === 0));
      let valid =  parseFloat(control.value) % 1 === 0;
      return valid ? null : {
          wholeNumber: {
            valid: false
       }
     }
   }
}
```

}

We can pass in a CustomValidator in the consturctor of our (ex. AppPage) class like this.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
  public navParams: NavParams,
  public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

      this.formGroup = formBuilder.group({
      'tableName': ['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          CustomValidators.duplicates(this.existingTables),
      ])],

      'totalSeats': ['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.required, 
          CustomValidators.min(2), 
          CustomValidators.max(20), 
          CustomValidators.wholeNumber,
      ])] 

      });

}
```

SECOND WAY is to create a class separately, this might be easy to do when you don't have a lot of validators, otherwise you would have to make bunch of classes for each of them.

```
@Directive({ selector: '[validateDuplicates]' }) 
class ValidateDuplicates implements Validator {
   @Input('validateDuplicates') existing: string[];

    validate(control: FormControl): { [key: string]: any; } { 

        let valid = this.existing.map(s => s.toLowerCase().trim())
           .indexOf(control.value.toLowerCase().trim()) === -1;

       return valid ? null : {
            duplicates: {
               valid: false
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of your ion-input to 'tel' and you will be able to use minlength and maxlength

example:

```
        <ion-label stacked>Nombre para la tarjeta</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="tel" name="name" minlength="1" maxlength="11"
                   required [(ngModel)]="card.name">
        </ion-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below given code is a custom email validation directive in angular2. Hope it will help you.

```
import { Directive, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[validateEmail]',
  providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => ValidateEmail), multi: true }]
})
export class ValidateEmail implements Validator {

  constructor() { }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
    let EMAIL_REGEXP =  /^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i;

    if (!c.value) return null;
    return EMAIL_REGEXP.test(c.value) ? null : {
      validEmail: true
    };
  }
}
```